# Installing VirtualBox gives kernel, grub and graphics card errors

Tags: linux, virtualbox, opensuse, rpm, yast

I just tried booting into a virtual os and I got some error saying that I needed to check the kernel driver for vbox or whatever. I tried doing a `ps -ef | grep vbox` and also searched for the file. I couldn't find anything.

So I went into yast and removed all virtualbox packages. Then I reinstalled them (or tried to) in the terminal and I got a bunch of garble saying stuff about the kernel and about grub -- so now I'm a little rattled :) here's the output:

```
Retrieving package kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.5.1.x86_64 (1/6), 34.8 MiB (135.5 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.5.1.x86_64.rpm [done (496.1 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package ndiswrapper-kmp-default-1.56_k2.6.37.1_1.2-11.3.x86_64 (2/6), 107.0 KiB (431.0 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: ndiswrapper-kmp-default-1.56_k2.6.37.1_1.2-11.3.x86_64.rpm [done (0 B/s)]
Retrieving package preload-kmp-default-1.2_k2.6.37.6_0.5-6.7.3.x86_64 (3/6), 39.0 KiB (130.0 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: preload-kmp-default-1.2_k2.6.37.6_0.5-6.7.3.x86_64.rpm [done]
Retrieving package virtualbox-host-kmp-default-4.0.8_k2.6.37.6_0.5-8.1.x86_64 (4/6), 1.0 MiB (8.0 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: virtualbox-host-kmp-default-4.0.8_k2.6.37.6_0.5-8.1.x86_64.rpm [done (466.4 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package virtualbox-4.0.8-8.1.x86_64 (5/6), 10.3 MiB (25.4 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: virtualbox-4.0.8-8.1.x86_64.rpm [done (360.9 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package virtualbox-qt-4.0.8-8.1.x86_64 (6/6), 3.5 MiB (16.8 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: virtualbox-qt-4.0.8-8.1.x86_64.rpm [done (393.0 KiB/s)]
Installing: kernel-default-2.6.37.6-0.5.1 [done]
Additional rpm output:

Kernel image:   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.37.6-0.5-default
Initrd image:   /boot/initrd-2.6.37.6-0.5-default
KMS drivers:     radeon
Root device:    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-60Z0A0_WD-WCAV2M336077-part2 (/dev/sda2) (mounted on / as ext4)
Resume device:  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-60Z0A0_WD-WCAV2M336077-part1 (/dev/sda1)
Kernel Modules: thermal_sys processor thermal fan crc16 jbd2 ext4 i2c-algo-bit drm drm_kms_helper ttm radeon usbcore pcmcia_core pcmcia mmc_core ssb ohci-hcd ehci-hcd uhci-hcd usbhid 
(module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R520_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R520_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS600_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS600_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS690_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS690_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R420_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R420_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R300_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R300_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R200_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R200_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R100_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R100_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV710_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV710_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV730_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV730_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV770_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV770_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS780_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS780_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV670_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV670_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV635_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV635_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV620_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV620_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV630_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV630_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV610_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV610_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R600_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R600_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R600_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R600_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R520_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R520_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS600_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS600_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS690_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS690_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R420_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R420_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R300_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R300_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R200_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R200_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R100_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R100_cp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CYPRESS_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/JUNIPER_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/REDWOOD_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/CEDAR_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/R700_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/R600_rlc.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV710_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV710_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV710_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV730_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV730_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV730_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV770_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV770_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV770_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS780_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS780_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RS780_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV670_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV670_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV670_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV635_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV635_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV635_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV620_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV620_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV620_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV630_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV630_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV630_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV610_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV610_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/RV610_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R600_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R600_me.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-default/radeon/R600_pfp.bin) (module radeon.ko firmware /lib/firmware/2.6.37.6-0.5-desktop/radeon/R600_pfp.bin) Features:       kms block usb resume.userspace resume.kernel
Bootsplash:     openSUSE (1400x1050), openSUSE (1680x1050)
48821 blocks
Perl-Bootloader: 2011-05-18 17:15:37 WARNING: GRUB::Global2Info: Unknown global key updatedefaultentry


Installing: ndiswrapper-kmp-default-1.56_k2.6.37.1_1.2-11.3 [done]
Installing: preload-kmp-default-1.2_k2.6.37.6_0.5-6.7.3 [done]
Installing: virtualbox-host-kmp-default-4.0.8_k2.6.37.6_0.5-8.1 [done]
Installing: virtualbox-4.0.8-8.1 [done]
Additional rpm output:
creating group vboxusers...
insserv: warning: script 'S01vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vpnagentd_init' missing LSB tags and overrides
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxBFE to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSDL to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetAdpCtl to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxNetDHCP to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)


Installing: virtualbox-qt-4.0.8-8.1 [done]
Additional rpm output:
setting /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox to root:vboxusers 4750. (wrong permissions 0755)
```

There's even stuff about my graphics card there. I've been having some issues with GRUB and booting into a windows install so maybe its that...?

Can anyone make any sense of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in there looks bad.

VirtualBox requires a kernel module to work, and the version of VirtualBox you installed requires the latest version of the Linux kernel, which you had not yet updated, so `yast` updated that for you.  It spewed a bunch of debug info about the kernel out, but there is nothing in there to be concerned about.  Installing a new kernel requires pointing GRUB to it, which is why that was mentioned.

It appears that VirtualBox, its kernel module, and the latest version of the Linux kernel for your system were installed successfully, and you shouldn't get that error from VirtualBox when you try it again.  You will need to reboot before using VirtualBox, however, as that is necessary to load the updated kernel.

If you continue to experience problems, please post a new question with the specific error you are getting from VirtualBox.

Comment: Great answer and yeah you're completely right. Running DSL as we speak :) thanks